# How to make jquery autocomplete to work for a contenteditable DIV instead of just INPUT, TEXTAREA fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, jquery-plugins, jquery-autocomplete

The jquery autocomplete provided by http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete can work on a INPUT field or a TEXTAREA field. I have a use-case to make a DIV element act as a TEXTAREA by setting its attribute to contenteditable="true". Can I use the DIV's DOM handle for the autocompleter to behave as a textarea for the autocompleter. Currently the plugin 'as is' is not working for the DIV. What changes should I do for the plugin to work for all the above elements?

Comment: Basically I am trying to implement a facebook like autosuggest for contacts when "@" key is pressed followed by search string that would send a remote request (and cache the request for subsequent use for the same handler). Also I want to render html inside the textbox, so preferring a contenteditable DIV over a TEXTAREA.

Answer (score 0):

[How to make jquery autocomplete to work for a contenteditable DIV instead of just INPUT, TEXTAREA fields.](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-make-jquery-autocomplete-to-work-for-a-contenteditable-div-instead-of-just-input-textarea-fields)

Answer (score -1):

Tags on a page matter. If your div wants to act like a textarea, maybe it should be a textarea styled to look like a div. You can render your html in a separate div and position it on top of the text area.

Comment: I disagree that a `div` positioned on top of a `textarea` would behave the way the OP desires.